# Shopware on reverse proxy - tries to download js from localhost

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, shopware6

I'm trying to put production shopware on a server and add a domain to it. The domain added to nginx, and here is my configuration.

```
server {

   server_name shopware.mydomain.com;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
      proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;   
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_hide_header Content-Security-Policy;
      proxy_hide_header X-Content-Type-Options;
      proxy_hide_header Referrer-Policy;
    }

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/shopware.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/shopware.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = shopware.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


   listen 80;

   server_name shopware.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Where let's say "mydomain" is just my domain. Here is my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
91.205.75.138 199047.webh.me 199047

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1 mydomain.com shopware.mydomain.com
```

I installed Shopware, but when I go into /admin, I get a JavaScript error caused by shopware trying to download js from http://localhost:8085 instead of the domain it is assigned. How do I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who will have problems in the future. Shopware by default provides a docker image that includes nginx and php. In my case, there was an external nginx that handled the domain and SSL certificate, while this nginx inside the docker image overwrote my requests. So I split these images into smaller ones as follows:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/nginx/ssl
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./php-fpm/Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.25
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: secret
      MYSQL_USER: secret
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node

    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
```

Dockerfile for php-fpm

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl

COPY ./php-fpm/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change the `APP_URL` variable in your `.env` file, which is located in the root directory of your Shopware 6 instance.

```
# Change this url
# In your .env File
APP_URL="http://localhost:8085"
```

Comment: I already have my domain there

Comment: I added
```proxy_set_header Host $host; proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```
To my nginx config. Now I see that Shopware is getting assets from domain, but still through the http, not https